# Create a job in Jenkins automatically when a repo is created in Phabricator

Tags: jenkins, phabricator

I have a repo in [phabricator](https://www.phacility.com/) and cloned in my local machine.

Now I want to create a new Jenkins job automatically after creating a new repo in Phabricator. Jenkins API is available to create a new job remotely.

According to Jenkins:

> To create a new job, post config.xml to this URL with query parameter name=JOBNAME. You need to send a Content-Type: application/xml header.

I can create a job by the following command using `terminal`.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -d "<project><builders/><publishers/><buildWrappers/></project>" "http://ip:port/createItem?name=AA_TEST_JOB1"
```

**Question:** How can I run the command by Harbormaster to create a Jenkins job and also send `config.xml` file for the configuration of that new job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Actually, there is no settings or automatic way to create a Jenkins job after creating a new repo in Phabricator.
- I've solved this editing Phabricator php codes. Simple way is to call the Jenkins API from php codes after creating a repo.

Answer (score 1):

Guy Warner (http://www.guywarner.com/) has done a lot of work to show how this is possible. You can visit his blog post for more details: http://www.guywarner.com/2014/05/integrating-jenkins-and-phabricator.html (part 1) and http://www.guywarner.com/2014/06/part-2-integrating-phabricator-and.html (part 2).

The basic idea is that your Harbormaster Build Plan will make an HTTP request to your Jenkins instance.

We used his tutorials to setup almost 100 builds that trigger from Phabricator based on different types of changes.